# How to set the module name of a dynamically created class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3 to create a dynamic class:

```
def setup(namespace):
    namespace['a'] = 1

A = types.new_class('A', bases=(), kwds=None, exec_body=setup)

class B:
    b = 2

print(A)
print(B)
```

**Output**:

```
<class 'types.A'>
<class '__main__.B'>
```

I would like to put the class `A` also in the `__main__` module/scope (instead of the `types` module/scope). How can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `__module__` attribute after the fact:

```
A.__module__ == '__main__'
```

You can do this in the `exec_body` callable:

```
def setup(namespace):
    namespace['a'] = 1
    namespace['__module__'] = '__main__'
```

Demo:

```
>>> import types
>>> def setup(namespace):
...     namespace['a'] = 1
...
>>> A = types.new_class('A', bases=(), kwds=None, exec_body=setup)
>>> A.__module__ = '__main__'
>>> A
<class '__main__.A'>
```

or with the `exec_body()` callable:

```
>>> def setup(namespace):
...     namespace['a'] = 1
...     namespace['__module__'] = '__main__'
...
>>> A = types.new_class('A', bases=(), kwds=None, exec_body=setup)
>>> A
<class '__main__.A'>
```

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I don't, not in Python 3.6. What version of Python are you using?